# area51 reputation report seems to be adding 2 for "meh" votes rather then subtracting 2

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, area-51

Here's an excerpt from my reputation report (`http://area51.stackexchange.com/reputation`) over on Area 51:

```
2      1289 (5)
22     1282 (2)**
2      1271 (5)
2      1150 (5)
22      416 (2)**
```

The interesting items are those marked **.

These correspond to "meh" (not a good example) votes. My total reflects these as does my [reputation tab](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/87?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top). I'm not sure how much of this others will see, but if you can see it scroll down to the bottom of the list and you'll see a couple of -2's.

The total in the report also treats them as +2 rather than -2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that the reputation report is now showing -2 for "Meh" votes:

```
 22      968 (-2)
 2      1150 (5)
 2      1150 (5)
 2       968 (5)
 2      1285 (5)
 2      1271 (5)
 22     1282 (-2)
```

Comment: I've added this answer and I'll accept it to avoid the question being bumped by the Community user in the future.